# Infinite document validator pattern - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, validation, types, document

I am new to MongoDB and I'm trying to create a document validator for a folder tree. The goal of this document is to represent where the different folders and documents are located in a user's storage.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to describe the fact that each folder may have multiple folders inside them.

What I've came up so far with is this:

```
{
  bsonType: "object",
  required: ["rootTree"],
  properties: {
    rootTree: {
      bsonType: 'object',
      properties: {
        files: {
          bsonType: [
            'array'
          ],
          items: {
            bsonType: 'object',
            required: [
              'file_id',
              'name'
            ],
            properties: {
              file_id: {
                bsonType: 'objectId',
                description: 'the id of the file stored in the File collection'
              },
              name: {
                bsonType: 'string',
                description: 'the name of the file'
              }
            }
          }
        },
        folders: {
          bsonType: [
            'array'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in this document validator I say that at the root of the storage I can store different files, and folders. And I'd to say that in each folder I can store many files and folders as well, but if I continue to define what is inside a folder, it will continue forever.

Do you have any idea on how I could proceed to define this behavior? (without creating a collection for the folders preferably)

For instance, can I create something like a folder type in this case?

Comment: Two issues.  1. MongoDB has a nesting depth maximum of 100 so forget about "infinite."   2.  You can store recursively nested docs but you cannot create a validation schema for them because the #ref statement is not part of the mongodb validation engine.

Comment: You can try applying the Modeling of Tree Structures.

Comment: ... or, go parent/child using reference IDs and employ `$graphLookup` to bring it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use another solution to describe a file tree organisation which is using a "path" field indication the location of the file/folder.

So this question is not relevant for me anymore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).